# Move Glyphicons Lower

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm using a custom font for my webpage. Unfortunately it's not a standard font and its offset is not correct. When I use this font with twitter bootstrap glyphicon together they won't appear in the same line.

How can I move the glyphicon a little lower? Or is there any other good solution for fixing this?

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> My Text</a></li>
```

[image: More Clear]

Comment: The kerning on the `Te` is _terrible_!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the position with simple css. Using a relative unit like `em` should work for all font sizes. You might need to set up more rules and use `px` for pixel perfect aligning.

```
.glyphicon { 
  top: 0.5em;
}
```

```css
.glyphicon  { 
  top: 0.5em !important;
  /* You can omit `!important` if you include your css after the glyphicon css */
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> My Text</a></li>
</ul>
```